# What is TensorFlow Eager module for?

Tags: tensorflow, eager

Github links to the newly introduced Eager modules in tensorflow:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/c/eager
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/eager

Comment: I think the answer of this question should be updated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to an [article](https://medium.com/@yaroslavvb/tensorflow-meets-pytorch-with-eager-mode-714cce161e6c) written by a Google former intern explaining `tensorflow` `eager mode`.

Basically this is a mode in tensorflow that allows writing imperative coding style, like with `numpy`. So there should be no explicit `graph`, `session`, `session.run()` anymore. The graph is implicitly built when the code runs like in `Chainer`/`PyTorch`.

It is still under active development and the performance is still not as good as it could be. You can try it via the nightly build on `pip` while expecting some interesting new features like `graph function`, which allows calling a subgraph as a function. As the framework evolves, this should possibly be the default mode for `tensorflow`.

**Update:** Tensorflow team has officially [talked about it](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/79xj5h/n_tensorflow_eager_execution_an_imperative/).

> Eager execution is an imperative, define-by-run interface where
>   operations are executed immediately as they are called from Python.
>   This makes it easier to get started with TensorFlow, and can make
>   research and development more intuitive.
>
> A vast majority of the TensorFlow API remains the same whether eager
>   execution is enabled or not. As a result, the exact same code that
>   constructs TensorFlow graphs (e.g. using the layers API) can be
>   executed imperatively by using eager execution. Conversely, most
>   models written with Eager enabled can be converted to a graph that can
>   be further optimized and/or extracted for deployment in production
>   without changing code.
>
> You can read out more about it in the [blog post](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/10/eager-execution-imperative-define-by.html) or the [README](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/README.md). This is
>   still a preview release, so you may hit some rough edges.
>
> Looking forward to your feedback as you try it out.

**Update:** Eager mode is now official released in [TF 1.7](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.7.0). There is a nice [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager) on their website. I guess everyone knows what it is by now, all major frameworks converge, dynamic neural networks.

**Update:** Eager mode will be the default mode in TF 2.0, the next major version [planned for release](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/bgug1G6a89A) later this year 2018.

Answer (score 6):

According to these tweets:

- https://twitter.com/oshtim/status/879453382326353920
- https://twitter.com/breandan/status/879455797641719809
- https://twitter.com/mtesfald/status/879455326432632832

Eager is a new imperative mode in tensorflow (and not the same as [the imperative module in contrib](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/imperative)).

Answer (score 2):

Eager execution is an imperative, define-by-run interface where operations are executed immediately as they are called from Python.

Visit https://research.googleblog.com/2017/10/eager-execution-imperative-define-by.html for more detail information.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

(Ready to run in 1.5rc0)

User Guide:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/g3doc/guide.md

Example Codes:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples